# Does ros have some package that can provide linear and circular interpolation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, I am using ros to control a six-dof robot arm and can realize inverse kinematics.

Now I want to control it to move in the cartesian space, which may need linear and circular interpolation,
so how could achieve this fastly as I am new about this and does ros have some package can help me do this?

Thank you for help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256456/does-ros-have-some-package-that-can-provide-linear-and-circular-interpolation/) by [yin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25699/yin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2017-03-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the DRC we used piecewise linear cartesian motions to approximate circular motion. A helper function for this is [getCircularArcPoses](https://github.com/team-vigir/vigir_manipulation_planning/blob/master/vigir_moveit_utils/include/vigir_moveit_utils/constrained_motion_utils.h#L49) , which just generates poses lying on a circular arc. An example of it being called is [here](https://github.com/team-vigir/vigir_manipulation_planning/blob/264b63e53f6631ca9ffe19976fd3949630ce3600/vigir_move_group/src/manipulation_action_capability.cpp#L612). The poses are then forwarded to MoveIt's cartesian planner starting [here](https://github.com/team-vigir/vigir_manipulation_planning/blob/264b63e53f6631ca9ffe19976fd3949630ce3600/vigir_move_group/src/manipulation_action_capability.cpp#L639) and then sent to the robot for execution.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0